# Grails 2.4.4 bindData - use '_' as prefix separator instead of '.'?

Tags: grails, data-binding, namespaces

I have a request from the client in which all the fields are prefixed by 'x_'. I know bindData supports stripping out prefixes before binding with a command object (described [here](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.4/ref/Controllers/bindData.html)), but it appears to only support prefixes separated by '.' by default. Is there a way to use configure it to look for the 'x_' namespace instead?

Comment: Looking at the [Grails DataBinding code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-databinding/src/main/groovy/grails/databinding/SimpleDataBinder.groovy#L219), this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into writing a servlet filter to modify the fields coming in. Here's an example of one that changes camelCase to snake_case - You should be able to modify it to meet your needs.

https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails-snakecase-params/tree/master/src